# How can I insert my Python code in an HTML page?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, dynamic-html

I am having an HTML page or I would say an inline styling HTML page. This page requires some dynamic information to pass on. I have a separate python code that pull all my dynamic content from various sources. Now I need to integrate my python code in an HTML page and open that page in the outlook compose email. So that the user simply add some information and send that email further.

Which package should I need to use to fulfill my requirement? I was googling it and found CGI and Flask modules, but I'm not familiar with these. Kindly suggest the best and appropriate module to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you need dynamic content on your web page with help of flask, there are two approaches.

First is you render whole page on the server side using jinja template engine.

Second is, having some basic page, you make an ajax request to the flask server, get the required data and then insert it in your page using javascript.

First one is much simpler and if you don't need any user intercaction, [this link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates) would help you.

All you need is just like this

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/')
@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('hello.html', name=name)
```

And actually, create a template

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Hello from Flask</title>
{% if name %}
  <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
{% else %}
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Your file structure should be like this

```
/app.py
/templates
    /hello.html
```

This should work. But I strongly recommend to read flask's docs first.

Comment: Thanks @Montreal for the solution. I followed flask approach and it worked for me.

Comment: @AshishSharma, always glad to help :)